# Django ORM: Compare substring

Tags: django, django-orm

Is there a way to compare the last 10 characters of a column (type string) in database using django ORM query. I want to do something like:

```
foo = '1234567890'
result= db.objects.filter(col1[-10:]=foo).values('name')
```

But col1[-10:] doesn't work. Is there any alternative for this?

Note: foo can be less than 10 characters and we want to match the last characters or maximum possible characters. foo='67890' shouldn't match '1234567890' but only '67890'. However, foo='1234567890' should match '991234567890'.

Answer (score 3):

Use django endswith filter: https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#std:fieldlookup-endswith

```
model.objects.filter(col1__endswith=foo).values('name')
```

What you have tried would raise SyntaxError.

Comment: If foo = '67890' then with this approach '1234567890' will match foo, but it shouldn't. I want all the last 10 characters to match. If col1 has an entry which has less than 10 characters then it should match whole entry, like col1[-10:]=foo. Maybe it wasn't clear from my question. I'll update it.

Comment: You should use some conditions to check the length of foo in python and customize your queryset based on that. It is not really clear what you want to achieve.